# Single word for "show while listening for events/requests"

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

The majority of components in a computer program I'm currently developing are allowed to "present" themselves to an external entity through a given medium (e.g., to a user through a pre-defined UI glyphs).

Whenever I ask them to do so, I will invoke the following command:

`show(Medium)`

A subset of said components, however, have slightly more privilege: not only that they are allowed to present themselves, they are also given the power to listen to interactions in the form of events and/or requests made, again, by an external entity.

As of this moment, the command looks like the following:

`showAndListen(InteractiveMedium)`

But I find that command to be rather clunky and in the need of a better name.

Is there any single word alternatives to `showAndListen`?

Comment: Off-topic: naming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because naming requests are specifically so.

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen this word used, but there's a term called 'transput', which is both input and output together.

Though I would do something like

command_O()

and

command_IO( )

for distinguishing input/output.

Answer (score -1):

I would named the command **Avail**.

In other words, the component is making itself available, both in the sense of appearance and being able to respond to the external entity's requests.

Answer (score -1):

Your question contains its own answer:

```
interact(…)
```

A more jargony option is

```
interface(…)
```

but that doesn't clearly imply a bi-directional data flow.

A more conversational (less jargony) option, which has fewer syllables, is

```
converse(…)
```